# OCRopus installing problem

Tags: software-installation, python, mv, ocr

I'm working on a project and need to use OCRopus, I tried to install it on windows but failed, so I moved to Ubuntu. I'm not a nerdy when it comes to Ubuntu, so I'm stuck now.

I have installed `python 2.7` and all the requirements 1 and 2, also I've installed opencv.

Then I tried to install ocropy as written in this [link](https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy/blob/master/README.md):

```
$ sudo apt-get install $(cat PACKAGES)
$ wget -nd http://www.tmbdev.net/en-default.pyrnn.gz
$ mv en-default.pyrnn.gz models/
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

But failed at this line:
`mv en-default.pyrnn.gz models/`

I got the following message:
`mv: cannot move ‘en-default.pyrnn.gz’ to ‘models/’: Not a directory`

I actually don't understand the command, because previous line gets a `.gz` then we want to move it to a model directory (which is not created yet!) then we need to run `setup.py` which is not there.

So I don't know if I'm missing something.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps is misleading for you, use this:

You need to clone the master tree in order to proceed with the installation.

You need git via `apt-get install git`.

```
$ mkdir workingcopy/
$ cd workingcopy/
$ git init .
$ git pull https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy
$ sudo apt-get install $(cat PACKAGES)
$ wget -nd http://www.tmbdev.net/en-default.pyrnn.gz
$ mv en-default.pyrnn.gz models/
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: I tried your code but got the following: python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.. the .gz file doesn't contain a setup.py actually! it contains this file: en-default.pyrnn

Comment: ok i think i got your problem, i have edited the answer. Try again.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!! so that's what I was missing I feel so.....aagh :)